# DOM Document PHP Replace TD

Tags: php, dom

I would like to be pointed in the right direction on how I would go about editing data (not headings) of a table using PHP DOM Document.

I have been looking into PHP DomDocument to replace the content of "Name 1" and "Age 1" etc, with real data from a database, however I am having a few issues...

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('template.html');

$sql = 'SELECT name,
               age
        FROM db.people';

$sql = mysql_query($sql);

for($i=0; $person = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); $i++)
{
    $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item($i)->nodeValue = $person['name'];
}

$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $doc->saveHTML();

?>
```

I would like to continue editing the above PHP code to replace place holder data with data from a database.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stephanie</td>
        <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Martin</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sarah</td>
        <td>61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kevin</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, and if i'm on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both assignments inside the loop are assigning to exactly the same element, except the top one assigns "name" to the element, and the bottom one assigns "age" to the element.  So Age always wins.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense, but how do I asign the name value and age value to each of the td's for each row?